# Use a class as type specifier before it is defined

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

So I am having trouble with the way classes are being used in `std::variant`.

Say I have the folowing code:

```cpp
// abc.h
#include <variant>

class A
{
public:
    A(std::variant<B, C> data);
};

class B
{
public:
    B(std::variant<A, C> data);
};

class C
{
public:
    A(std::variant<A, B> data);
};
```

It would give me errors like `error C2065: 'NameOfClass': undeclared identifier` when I try to use classes that haven't been declared yet. What would be a good solution for this? In my actual project there are quite a number of classes that use each other in `variant`s.

Comment: I'm curious why you want `std::variant` constructor parameters instead of just overloading the constructor? But regardless, you just need to add some forward declarations for `B` and `C`.

Comment: @Brian Will `std::variant` work with incomplete types?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm good point. That I don't know. Presumably not

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't think it will. Only standard library templates that explicitly say they work with incomplete types can be relied on to do so.

Comment: @Brian So in my actual project, some of the classes has constructors that contains two variant type parameters, each variant consisting of around 5 - 10 types, so I don't think I would want to write so many constructors. And I will have a look at forward declarations.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `variant<A, B, C>`, all three classes `A`, `B`, and `C` must be complete - since otherwise the compiler can't figure out how big the variant has to be.

On the other hand, you should be able to *declare them*; but when the time comes to actually *use* a `VAR`, they must all be complete.

```
class A;
class B;
class C;
using VAR = std::variant<A, B, C>; // a declaration

class A {int a;};
class B {long b;};
class C {double c;};

VAR v; // a definition.
```

Comment: So what I wanted to achieve would be impossible in this case? Is it possible at all to let the compiler know what classes are in the scope disregarding where they are declared/defined and use them? Thought C++ would be more clever than this.

Comment: Can’t we declare the desired constructors with such forward declarations and define them later?